# I can not find c++ winable.h for visual studio

Tags: visual-c++

I would like to ask you if you do know where I can Download c++ winable.h too visual studio. But today I spend half hour searching this.

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Have you read e.g. [this question and its answers](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/ee57cc38-1dc6-4a5f-b7e3-1f16dbd91b83/missing-winableh?forum=windowssdk)? The answers says that `winable.h` was obsoleted and that is basically isn't needed any more.

Comment: You will need to download an old version of the SDK (for example, [for Server 2003](http://download.cnet.com/Windows-Server-2003-SP1-Platform-SDK-ISO-Install/3000-2070_4-10731571.html), or check MSDN). Alternatively, you will need to update your code, as Joachim suggested.